# Problem with rsync in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, rsync

Im facing a problem with AppleScript/Rsync.

I try to copy various folders from various drives to one HDD.
The following shows a part of the Apple script which is more or less always the same part of code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if (disk "MAC SSD X5" exists) then
        do shell script "rsync -azvp '/Volumes/MAC SSD X5' '/Volumes/Backup/MAC SSD X5' --progress --partial  --delete --backup  --backup-dir='/Volumes/Backup/Gelöschte\ Dateien'"
        
    end if
end tell
```

If I run this in Applescript it works. But uses rsync 2.6.9 which has less functions and less performance.

While if I run:

```
 rsync -azvp '/Volumes/MAC\ SSD\ X5' '/Volumes/Backup/MAC\ SSD\ X5' --progress --partial  --delete --backup  --backup-dir='/Volumes/Backup/Gelöschte\ Dateien'
```

directly in the terminal it uses rsync Version 3.2.3 from another folder.

I tried to remove the former Version (2.6.9) of rsync but I didn't succeed.

Also I tried to add

```
--rsync-path=/usr/bin/local/rsync
```

in Applescript.
But it still uses rsync 2.6.9.
Also if I add the path of the rsync 2.6.9 in Terminal it will uses the new rsync (so the flag is not working either way).

Hope anyone can help me out with this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not the case of your error, as **nohillside** already address it, however a comment about your _code_: The `do shell script` _command_ is a part of **Standard Additions** in **AppleScript**. not **Finder** and as such should not be wrapped within the `tell application "Finder"` _block_ as it actual throws a _non-fatal error_. Proper coding in this use case would be to use **Finder** to set a _flag_ and a separate _code block_ to act on the _flag_ or use `tell me to` or `tell current application to` in front of the `do shell script` _command_.

Comment: Setting a _flag_ and a separate _code block_ to act on the _flag_ is the more proper way to go in this use case.

Comment: Since I am a beginner could you give me examples on that "proper ways"? Thank You!

Comment: As `exists disk` returns a _boolean_, I'd use **System Events**, (because it's faster than **Finder**), to set a _boolean flag_, e.g. `diskExists` by coding, e.g., `tell application "System Events" to set diskExists to (exists disk "MAC SSD X5")`. Now the _value_ of `diskExists` is either _true_ or _false_, so then to conditionally execute the `do shell script` _command_, I'd code, e.g., `if diskExists then do shell script "..."` -- This way _commands_ that are not a part of an _application's_ **AppleScript** _dictionary_ are not being wrapped within its `tell` _block_.

Comment: The bottom line is, even if a line of code throws a non-fatal error it shouldn't be used and it should be written so it doesn't throw an error unless it's a situation where a _trappable error_ could occur or might be expected, in which case coding for proper _error handling_ should be employed.

Answer (score 4):

- Run `type rsync` in Terminal and take note of the path (I assume `/usr/local/bin/rsync` but this may be different in your case)
- Call this version of rsync in your AppleScript

  ```
  do shell script "/usr/local/bin/rsync -azvp '/Volumes/MAC SSD X5' '/Volumes/Backup/MAC SSD X5' - ...
  ```

PS: `--rsync-path` is used to "specify the rsync to run on remote machine" which isn't relevant if you rsync between locally-mounted volumes.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked for me!